# Error when using tensorflow to load frozen graph because of AssignVariableOp

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to freeze a third party model checkpoint originally created using tensorflow 1.12.0
and convert it into a pb graph so that I can use it on a different platform.

This is the guide I followed to freeze the model.

https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc

```
# We start a session using a temporary fresh Graph
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    # We import the meta graph in the current default Graph
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(input_checkpoint + '.meta', clear_devices=clear_devices)
    
    # We restore the weights
    saver.restore(sess, input_checkpoint)

    output_node_names = [<my list of output node I need>]

    # We use a built-in TF helper to export variables to constants
    output_graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
        sess, # The session is used to retrieve the weights
        tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(), # The graph_def is used to retrieve the nodes 
        output_node_names # The output node names are used to select the usefull nodes
    ) 

    # Finally we serialize and dump the output graph to the filesystem
    with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph, "wb") as f:
        f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

However, when I tried to load that pb graph with the following code.

```
with tf.io.gfile.GFile(pb_path, "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    # The name var will prefix every op/nodes in your graph
    # Since we load everything in a new graph, this is not needed
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
```

I ran into the following error.

> Input 0 of node .../AssignVariableOp was passed float from .../conv1d/queue:0 incompatible with expected resource.

Since I did not create the model myself, I cannot modify the architecture of the model much.
Is there anything I can do with a pre-trained checkpoint to solve this problem?
I've seen conflicted information on the internet regarding whether AssignVariableOp can even be frozen at all.

My current settings:

- Tensorflow 1.14.0
- Windows 10 Pro

This is what I've tried but did not fix the problem:

- Upate tensorflow to version 1.15.0 or the newest 2.x version.
- Set learning phase to 0 before freezing the model per this [link](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/incompatible-with-expected-resource/72935/4).
- Use intel-analytics's version of convert_variables_to_constants per this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25721).